# Is it possible to change page's title while keeping the page's original title in chrome://history?

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome-extension, tabs, browser-history

I'm doing a chrome extension to manager tabs, and I need change their titles, but I also want to keep their original titles in chrome://history, but chrome always updates the page's modified title immediately, I've tried so many times and still struggling with it.

I've tried these following unsuccessful methods:

1. Using `chrome.history.pushState()` or `chrome.history.replaceState()`.
2. Deleting a history entry then add this entry again with it's original title, chrome doesn't support that way (New added entry won't have title nor favicon).
3. Changing title back before closing the tab.
4. Changing chrome database directly (Extra native application will be needed).

....

So is it possible to do this for chrome ?

Comment: AFAIK no. As for #4 it'll work probably but it requires exiting Chrome first.

Comment: Thanks @OxxOm, you always support me,  that's too sad,  feel too restrictive to use those mainstream web browsers,  need to make one myself. :(

Comment: Consider adding a thin div at the top of the page with the text. It can have a customizable color/size/position via CSS.

Comment: My extension working almost perfectly but only has that flaw, don't know why, history entry deletion or aggregation is allowed by chrome except modification.